# Copying and pasting directly from GIMP has black background

Tags: gimp, transparency, copy-and-paste

Sometimes I edit an image in GIMP with transparency and copy the entire canvas and paste it directly into another application, such as a tweet on Twitter or a message on Discord. The image pastes with transparency pixels without any problems.

[image]

Lately, I noticed that copying images and pasting them anywhere outside of GIMP replaces the usual transparent pixels with a black background.

[image]

This really throws a wrench into my daily GIMP usage, and while I will eventually resort to saving the image and manually uploading it if I really have to, I have the feeling there's a setting somewhere that can change this back, since this is something that started happening without me updating the software.

What should I try first? Thanks in advance.

Comment: OS? Gimp version? No such problem for me on either 2.8 or 2.10. Are you using a clipboard manager?

Comment: @xenoid - I can replicate the issue with GIMP 2.10 and Windows 10.  Perhaps it's a bug?  Windows clipboard has always been a bit flaky The OP would be better reporting the issue or finding out if the bug has already been reported.

Comment: It's true with GIMP 2.10 in Win7, too. Copying an image to clipboard  presents transparency in a way that all other applications do not notice it, but some do. GIMP and Inkscape see the transparency ok, lecacy Photoshop doesn't.

Comment: Yeah I'm on 2.10.4 on Win10 x64, without a clipboard manager. Managed to reproduce this on other computers so I submitted a bug report here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/1995.